# How to restrict entering of custom text to a combo box in wix

Tags: wix

I need to stop users entering a custom text to a combo box. It should only allow users to select a item in the combo box, but not allow them to enter a custom text. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `ComboList` attribute to `Yes` for the parent `Control` element:

```
<Control Id="..." Type="ComboBox" ComboList="Yes" ...>
  <ComboBox Property="...">
    <ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="Item1"/>
    <ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="Item2"/>
    ...
  </ComboBox>
</Control>
```

Read more about `ComboList` attribute [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367987.aspx).